# How to parse HTMl text that contains single and double quotes

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, html-parsing

So, I was trying to make a scraper, with Selenium, of a webnovel that I wanted to read, but when I parse the HTML and write to a file, the single and double quotes turn into diamonds with question marks. I searched but I couldn't find anything. I think it has to do with unicode, but I don't know too much about it. Anyway, this is my code:

```
url = 'https://parahumans.wordpress.com/2011/06/11/1-1/'
driver.get(url)

chapter_name = driver.find_element_by_class_name('entry-title')
print(chapter_name.text)

text_div = driver.find_element_by_class_name('entry-content')
text = text_div.find_elements_by_tag_name('p')

with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), path), 'w') as file:
   for paragraph in text[3:]:
       file.write(paragraph.text + '\n')
```

and the output in the .txt file is:

```
Since the start of the semester, I had been looking forward to the part of Mr. Gladly�s World 
Issues class where we�d start discussing capes.  Now that it had finally arrived, I couldn�t 
focus.  I fidgeted, my pen moving from hand to hand, tapping, or absently drawing some figure 
in the corner of the page to join the other doodles.  My eyes were restless too, darting from 
the clock above the door to Mr. Gladly and back to the clock.  I wasn�t picking up enough of 
his lesson to follow along.  Twenty minutes to twelve; five minutes left before class ended.
```

Comment: This seems like an encoding issue.

Comment: Yes, it probably is, but I don't know what to do to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

There you go my friend, it scrapes all chapters from the Web Serial and save it to a file called `Worm.txt` you can change to whatever you want, i also included a progress bar using the built-in `tqdm` so you can check the progress, there are over 300 chapters, and each one takes about 1s to scrape, so expect it to take at least 5 minutes, but still much faster than using `selenium`.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from tqdm import tqdm

f = open("Worm.txt", "w")
a = requests.get("https://parahumans.wordpress.com/table-of-contents/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(a.text, "lxml")
text_div = soup.find("", {"class": "entry-content"})
links = text_div.find_all("a", href=True)[:-2]
for url in tqdm(links):
    a = requests.get(url['href'])
    soup = BeautifulSoup(a.text, "lxml")
    text_div = soup.find("", {"class": "entry-content"})
    text = text_div.find_all("p")
    for paragraph in text[3:]:
        f.write(paragraph.text + '\n')
f.close()
```

Comment: not necessarily, I only need it to change to the next page, not to retrieve the data. I tried using BeautifulSoup, but it didn't work. The singe and double quotes continues turning into diamonds with question marks.

Comment: For me the code works, it outputs the text without `�`. Why do you need selenium to change to the other page? you can just get the link and do another request.

Comment: yes, I could do that, but there are hundreds of pages to scrape. Can I do it with only bs4 and requests? If yes, it would be better.

Comment: Yes you can let me try to adapt the code.

Comment: Do you know how many chapters there are?

Comment: I can count it, but I noticed that the urls contains the date where the author posted it, so it is unpredictable.

Comment: I updated the code. Try it now.

Comment: I got it. The problem was not with my code or yours. I was opening it in VSCode, and for some reason, some characters turned into diamonds with questions marks, but I opened with my notepad and it was perfectly haha. Anyway, thanks for the help.